# does character ' and ` equal in mysql command?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select 'user_url' from wp_users;
mysql> select `user_url` from wp_users;
```

It can get the same result ,does  character ' and ` equal in mysql command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

' or " for strings

` (backtic) for column/table/database names.

The first should give you `user_url`; the second should look up the value in the user_url column.